# Cech cohomology and the simplicial cohomology of the nerve of an open cover.

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I am familiar with the usual nerve of a small category. Is there any way to construct the nerve of an open covering $\{U_i\}$ as the nerve of some small category?

How does the homology/cohomology of this simplicial set relate to the concept of Cech cohomology?

Call the nerve of the open covering $\{U_i\} \space$ X. Then define a chain complex $C_i = $ Free abelian group generated by $NU_i$ with $\partial=\sum(-1)^jd_j$, $d_j$ being the degeneracy maps of NU. Then we may take the homology/cohomology by applying Hom$(-,\mathbb Z)$.

The question I have now is if the Cech cohomology of the constant presheaf (not sheaf) $\mathbb Z$ is equal to the cohomology of $C^i = Hom(C_i, \mathbb Z)$. It seems obvious to me but don't want to go through all of the symbol pushing to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean Cech cohomology with respect to the fixed open covering or the inductive limit over all of them ?

Comment: With respect to the fixed open covering.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question in fact. And I am a bit confused by your construction. What does the free abelian group over a topological space means ? Do you mean the free abelian topological group or do you loose the topology. Do you mean continuous Homs ?

Comment: Im under the impression that NU is a simplicial set so NU_i is a set.

Comment: No you can't lose the topology like that. $NU$ is a simplicial topological space. Apply $Hom(.,\mathbb{Z})$ where $Hom$ means the set of *continuous* functions and you get Cech cohomology in the *sheaf* $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I guess that depends on which definition you choose, I thought the nerve of something is a simplicial set? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory)